# char * function not displaying correctly in C

Tags: c, char

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *czas()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer [80];
  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  strftime (buffer,80,"Now it's %I:%M%p.",timeinfo);
  return buffer;
}

int main()
{
printf("%s",czas());
system("PAUSE");
}
```

I dont know why, but result of this program is only "Press any key(...)". I've tried also to print it as %c but it still doesn't work. What is wrong with this program?

Comment: This is a classic error--everyone should make it once, after which they will understand about "scope".  BTW, since the "undefined" buffer may still be in memory, you are lucky it broke. Sometimes stuff like this doesn't get discovered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a static buffer unless you are sure you are never going to use this in multithreaded code, and that you'll never call it twice before using the first answer.

Malloc is an option, but forcing the caller to free the memory that a callee allocated can leave open issues of ownership and removes the possibility of using anything but heap memory for the buffer.

Your best bet, in my opinion, is to take a modification of Andrew Grant's suggest, but pass around the length of the buffer as well:

```
char *czas(char *buffer, size_t bufferLength)
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  strftime (buffer, bufferLength, "Now it's %I:%M%p.",timeinfo);
  return buffer;
}

int main()
{
   char buffer [80];
   printf("%s",czas(buffer, sizeof(buffer)));
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

Or

```
#define TIME_BUFFER_LENGTH 80
int main()
{
   char *buffer = malloc(TIME_BUFFER_LENGTH);
   if (buffer)
       printf("%s",czas(buffer, TIME_BUFFER_LENGTH));
   free(buffer);
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

This makes it easier to keep track of potential memory leaks, and buffer overflows.  You can look at `czas` and see that as long at the arguments are correct, the function is not going to overflow any buffers, or leak any memory.  Next, you can look at either version of `main` and see that no memory is leaked, and that the parameters passed to czas are correct (the bufferLength parameter accurately specifies the amount of space that buffer points to.)

Answer (score 10):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable ('buffer'), this is invalid and I'm surprised you don't receive a warning about it.

When a function exits all local variables cease to exist (known as going out of scope) and their memory will be used for other purposes. You are returning a pointer to this memory, but there's no guarantee what will now be there.

In this case it seems that at the time of the printf call the memory contains a 0 which is treated as an empty string. This is actually quite lucky, you could easily end up with either garbage being printed or the program crashing.

To resolve this you can either pass a buffer into czas, or have czas allocate a buffer on the heap which you later free. I would recommend the former because it is inline with how virtually all library functions work. It also avoids memory allocations where the caller must later free the pointer.

E.g:

```
size_t czas(char* buffer, size_t buffer_size)
{
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;

    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
    return strftime (buffer, buffer_size,"Now it's %I:%M%p.",timeinfo);
}

int main()
{
    char buffer [80];
    if (czas(buffer, 80))
    {
      printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Call to czas failed");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Update: I didn't notice that strftime took a size param, I've updated the code to use this and correctly pass back the result from strftime. As a result this is far more robust and you cannot accidentally overflow the buffer.

Comment: Also note that if you choose to address buffer potentially being too small, it is insufficient to check sizeof(buffer) inside of the czas function. This will only give you the size of a character pointer, not the size of the buffer. You must pass the buffer size as a second argument.

Answer (score 4):

The statement `char buffer [80];` makes `buffer` allocated in csas's stack.  Replace it with a call to `malloc` (`char *buffer = malloc (80)`) and you should be okay.  You'll have to free the buffer yourself later.

Answer (score 4):

Your return buffer in the function should be somewhere other than on the stack.  Since you have declared an auto variable as a fixed size array, it is on the stack.  You return a pointer to it, BUT, that space can then be "scribbled over" by subsequent function calls.

Either:

- use a static buffer, and realize that the function is not re-entrant
- allocate a buffer with malloc(), and remember to free() it afterward in the caller

Both options have drawbacks.  You will have 17 answers before I can enumerate them  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because buffer is a local variable that evaporates when the function returns - what you are seeing is undefined behaviour. A quick and dirty fix for this is to make the buffer static so that it hangs around after the function call - change:

```
char buffer [80];
```

to:

```
static char buffer [80];
```

Comment: Why do 1000 people say the same thing even though they see one person has entered the same answer?

Comment: This is not a good solution.  Making something static for the sake of returning a value is not the first-approach one should take.  This now makes the variable exist for the entire lifetime of the application.  Allocate the memory or use an out-parameter instead.

Comment: Well, for the first couple, they have the excuse that maybe they were typing when Neil was still typing.  But the guys who answered 3 or 4 minutes later, I'm not sure they have an excuse, although some of them took the time to write more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You call czas() but after you return, the buffer that czas created no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning 'buffer' which is allocated on the stack. But once the function returns, that part of the stack is no longer valid.

Either allocate memory for the returned string on the heap or use std::string as the return value.